# Word that describes a sentence which deals in absolutes

Tags: vocabulary

I'm looking for a word that can describe a statement that uses words (or sentiments) like "all" or "never" and applies to a wide domain. There is no implication of validity or accuracy, but I would be welcome to those suggestions as well.

"Sweeping" is as close as I can think of, but it feels like there is a better word for this.

Some examples:

> - Policemen are suspicious.
> - No children like broccoli.
> - All music is banned.

Thanks!

Comment: "hasty generalization" (*hasty* may be replaced by *rash* or *over-hasty*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Blanket**

I prefer blanket over sweeping because blanket implies everything is covered, whereas sweeping implies perhaps more than should be included, but not necessarily everything.

Comment: Great suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate you accepting my answer already, but I'd suggest checking back later to see if someone else comes up with a better answer. I'm relatively new to this site and don't consider myself an English expert (yet). It's possible my answer will be best, but likely not.

Comment: I plan on it :)

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence is inaccurate, it is a form of *[overstatement](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/overstatement)*

> The action of expressing or stating something too strongly; exaggeration:
>   *a classic piece of overstatement*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

It also could be referred to as *exaggeration* or *hyperbole*, although the latter is often used for a knowing overstatement.